# How to fix ValueError: read of closed file while parsing a pcap using dpkt

Tags: python, dpkt

I'm new to networking, I'm trying to parse a `pcap` using `dpkt`, but I'm getting

> ValueError: read of closed file.

Here's the code:

```
import dpkt
f = open('test.pcapng', 'rb')
pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)
for timestamp, buf in pcap:
print (timestamp)
```

and this is the result:

> 1542964953.074129 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\User\Documents\testdpkt1.py", line 19, in 
>       for ts, buf in pcap:   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\dpkt\pcap.py",
>   line 312, in **iter**
>       buf = self.**f.read(PktHdr.__hdr_len**) ValueError: read of closed file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
with open('test.pcapng', 'rb') as f:
    pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)
    for timestamp, buf in pcap:
        print (timestamp)
```

This should prevent the file from being closed